# Import functions into React Native Paper Bottom Navigation

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-paper

I am making a dynamic file that returns the BottomNavigation function from React Native Paper so that it can be called through a function call. I can't find a proper way of rendering the functions that I import into Bottom Navigation. Currently, the bottom navigation bar displays on the screen, but the buttons do not do anything on input (the functions do not fire). I have the Bottom Navigation file code:

```
import { BottomNavigation, Text } from 'react-native-paper';
import React, { Component, useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const PaperBottomNavigation = ({

  navigation, SceneMapFunctions, shifting, labeled, compact, activeColor, 
  inactiveColor, sceneAnimationEnabled, sceneAnimationType, keyboardHidesNavigationBar, 
  safeAreaInsets, barStyle, labelMaxFontSizeMultiplier, style, theme, testID

}) => {

  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);
  const [routes, setRoutes] = useState(navigation) 

  const renderScene=()=>{ // Set bottom navigation states (functions)
    var tempObjKeys = {}
    SceneMapFunctions.forEach((v,i)=>{
        if(navigation?.[i]?.key) // check if key exists
        {
            var tempKey = navigation?.[i]?.key // temp store key
            tempObjKeys[tempKey] = v // assign function to key
        } 
    })
    // Store Functions
      BottomNavigation.SceneMap(
        tempObjKeys
      );

  }

  return (
    <BottomNavigation
      key={navigation.length}
      navigationState={{ index, routes }}
      onIndexChange={setIndex}
      renderScene={renderScene}
      ...
    />
  );
};

export default PaperBottomNavigation;
```

The main issue is that renderScene does not build out each navigationState's action. "navigation" looks like this:

```
const navigation = [
        { key: 'musical', title: 'Favorite', focusedIcon: 'heart', unfocusedIcon: 'heart-outline'},
        { key: 'albums', title: 'Albums', focusedIcon: 'album' },
        { key: 'recents', title: 'Recents', focusedIcon: 'history' },
        { key: 'notifications', title: 'Notifications', focusedIcon: 'bell', unfocusedIcon: 'bell-outline' },
      ]
```

And SceneMapFunctions is an array of functions (each function returns a console.log):

```
const SceneMapFunctions = [MusicRoute, AlbumsRoute, RecentsRoute, NotificationsRoute]
```

I followed React Native Paper's guide illustrated in [React Native Paper](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/docs/components/BottomNavigation/), which uses the identical arrays as examples but does not import them as I do. I believe the issue lies in

```
BottomNavigation.SceneMap(tempObjKeys);
```

as in the example, this is stored in a constructor in the render scene, a lot different than how I implement it here. When storing it as a const, the functions fire when they are supposed to:

```
const renderScene = BottomNavigation.SceneMap({
    music: MusicRoute,
    albums: AlbumsRoute,
    recents: RecentsRoute,
    notifications: NotificationsRoute,
  });
```

However, this method is not compatible with importing functions into the component (where I build out tempObjKeys). How can I use this same methodology illustrated above, yet use imported functions and a built-out object, similar to:

```
const renderScene = BottomNavigation.SceneMap(tempObjKeys);
```

(This above code is not a valid method, as it returns: "Element Type is invalid: expected a string or a class function...")